# Can't debug azure solution after upgrading to sdk 2.2. Solution runs fine without debugging. Can attach debugger to running emulator

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I have a cloud solution with 2 roles: 1 web role, 1 worker role. The solution has recently been upgraded from sdk 2.1 where it worked fine.

If I run the solution without debugging e.g Ctrl-F5 the emulator fires up and the roles function as required. I can even attach a debugger to the running roles, though I have missed all role initialization by that point.

If I run with debugging e.g F5, the emulator starts up; the worker role gets stuck at "Role state busy", the web role gets stuck at "Role unhealthy" and visual studio becomes unresponsive and needs Task manager to kill. In VS the deploy animation in the lower RHS keeps running. Even if I comment out all the OnStart and Run overrides of the RoleEntryPoint s the same happens. I cannot hit any breakpoints no matter how early in app lifecycle so I am pretty sure it is an emulator infrastructure/ vs debugger issue.

I am currently running with assembly bind logging on and haven't noticed anything out of the ordinary. I have checked and rechecked that the sdk references in all projects and all dependencies have been upgraded.

If I run with debugging and with Role diagnostics enabled I get entries related to configuration updates added to the output even when everything else is frozen. e.g:

```
    [Diagnostics]: Checking for configuration updates 10/01/2014
```

I am looking for new lines of investigation, having exhausted everything I can think of. Incidentally this is not machine specific, I have tested on several machines and they all exhibit this behavior.

EDIT: I should note that other cloud solutions are debuggable even with the 2.2 sdk.

UPDATE: I am getting the following in the logs:

```
<Log>
    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Application Hang"/>
        <EventID Qualifiers="0">1002</EventID>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>101</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-17T18:53:34.000000000Z"/>
        <EventRecordID>1216077</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>devenv.exe</Data>
        <Data>12.0.21005.1</Data>
        <Data>2910</Data>
        <Data>01cf13b4114dc59b</Data>
        <Data>4294967295</Data>
        <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</Data>
        <Data>a94194c4-7fa8-11e3-bed7-001e4fea6057</Data>
        <Data/>
        <Data/>
        <Binary>54006F00700020006C006500760065006C002000770069006E0064006F0077002000690073002000690064006C00650000000000</Binary>
    </EventData>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0"/>
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">1325</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-17T18:56:06.000000000Z"/>
    <EventRecordID>1216080</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Computer>
    <Security/>
</System>
<EventData>
    <Data>Failed to initialize the AppDomain:/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOTException: System.SystemExceptionMessage: Failed to create AppDomain.StackTrace:    at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMExceptionMessage: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))StackTrace:    at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone&amp; zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence[T]()   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetDefaultDomainIdentity()   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0"/>
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">1325</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-17T18:56:06.000000000Z"/>
    <EventRecordID>1216080</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Computer>
    <Security/>
</System>
<EventData>
    <Data>Failed to initialize the AppDomain:/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOTException: System.SystemExceptionMessage: Failed to create AppDomain.StackTrace:    at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMExceptionMessage: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))StackTrace:    at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone&amp; zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence[T]()   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetDefaultDomainIdentity()   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
</Log>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to VS 2013 Update 2RC and installing the Azure 2.3 SDK has fixed the issue. (I have not upgraded the project to 2.3 yet)

Answer (score 3):

We have the same problem with our project. Microsoft bug report is here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817341/vs-debugger-cannot-attach-to-azurewebrole-with-more-then-one-iis-endpointbinding-when-using-iis-reproducable#

At this link there is also a (dirty) way around this problem. Let's hope MS will fix this issue soon.

Comment: This looks like a candidate. I have added my vote to connect.

Answer (score 2):

I had Visual Studio consistently hanging while trying to attach the debugger to the Azure Emulator. This was after an SDK / development environment upgrade of a project. The Emulator reported an "Role state unhealthy", I had to kill and restart Visual Studio. It turned out the problem was because the ServiceConfiguration contained:

```
<ServiceConfiguration osFamily="1">
```

and I was now running the Azure Emulator and Visual Studio running in Windows 8

Changing to

```
<ServiceConfiguration osFamily="3">
```

fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Originally I didn't have any osFamily configured. I tried 4 and 3 but no luck.

Comment: And if you re-create a new cloud project, and then copy the required settings?

Comment: Is there a chart somewhere that illustrates what the numbers mean?  I had this similar issue and my cfg was set to 4.  Changing it to 3 after reading this thread fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall SDK 2.2 and ALL previous versions of the SDK, then reinstall 2.2 and everything worked fine.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me, I uninstalled all the 2010, 2012 and 2013 sdks, and all the azure libraries, then installed the 2.2 sdk for vs 2013 but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I am still working through the why and how, but I have made progress; I added a new cloud project within the existing solution and added the existing roles to that project -  I left the old cloud project in place for reference. The new cloud project is debuggable, so now I can investigate the differences in the cdsef and cscfg.

EDIT: Unfortunately I had jumped the gun slightly. The newly created cloud project was using IIS Express, on switching it to IIS it failed again.

EDIT: By removing all but one of the configured endpoints (originally there were 4) and leaving just an http/80 I can debug, so the problem seems to be either ssl or internal endpoint related.

Answer (score 1):

My case was VERY similar to this. I had a Visual Studio 2010 Azure project using osFamily="1".  After I got Visual Studio 2013, I installed the latest Azure SDK for it, which right now is SDK 2.3.  I opened the project in Visual Studio 2013 and it did the conversion.

When I ran the project from Visual Studio 2013 **without** debugging, it would launch successfully.  When I tried to run in Debug mode (F5), it would just hang trying to launch compute emulator.  I hadn't changed the osFamily setting at first, but then I changed it to the correct osFamily="4" and that did not help.  Looking at the emulator log, many things were similar to what is in jaundice's post.  Mine started out in Role State Unhealthy.  It would do some other things then just get stuck in and endless loop of "[Diagnostics]: Checking for configuration updates".

What finally fixed it for me was changing the Emulator setting to use "Use Emulator Express".  As explained in [this article by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn339018.aspx), the Emulator Express appeared starting with Azure SDK 2.1 and is the default for 2.3 and later.  But if you convert from an old project, then it keeps the setting as "Use Full Emulator", which also requires full IIS.  Emulator Express uses IIS Express.  I thought at first that maybe it was just the change to IIS Express that made the difference, but I see that jaundice had it as IIS Express initially, so I think it was the Emulator Express that helped.  Not sure if everyone can use Emulator Express rather than Full Emulator, but its working for me.

[image: Emulator Settings]